# SQL: How do I get all rows 30 minutes after a specific timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to the query to return all rows which are ***x*** number of minutes after a specific timestamp, how do I go about achieving this?

Comment: Do you have a column with the timestamp in your table?

Comment: Yes I have a column with a timestamp

Comment: Lookup the MySQL TIMEDIFF function and use in your where clause

Comment: @SloanThrasher The thing is I have a previous where clause in which I want it to return all rows 30 minutes + after the timestamp of query which meets my initial where clause and this will happen repeatedly so how do I get this to repeat for every valid output.

Comment: There is now more information in the comments than in the question. When that happens, it's time to start over. Start by reading the 'help' pages. Then see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: There is no way to answer you question. Take @Strawberry advice. You should at the very least show the schema of the table(s) involved and the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE your_date_column> DATE_FORMAT(<specifictimestamp> + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE, '%Y-%m-01 %H:%i')
```